# Maximum size of a file resource in a Domino Database?

Tags: html5-video, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I need to use HTML5 to display a video on an Xpage and stored in the Domino Database. I did it with an .mp4 of small size no problem. Now I need to use a video that is 270MB. I get this error when I attempt to import as a file resource. Is there a maximum file size for a file resource? How do I get around this?

---

[image]

```
<xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1">
<xp:this.value>
<![CDATA[#{javascript:"<video width='320' height='240' controls>
<source src='fdbc.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>"}]]>
</xp:this.value></xp:text>
```

Comment: While this is not an answer to your problem you should think twice about what you are doing here: You are forcing a browser to download the whole 270 MB file before the video can be played. You should think about a streaming servlet which supports HTTP range requests (i.e. http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html)

Comment: Please show us your code. Are you storing the file in a rich text field?

Comment: I am not storing the file in RT field. I added the code to my original question.

Comment: How do you store the file then?

Comment: @Per: he stores it in Designer's Resources/Files. I tried it too: 130 MB work but 300 MB don't. I even tried it with WebContent Folder and OnDiskProjekt: no way to get such large files into Domino database design. Seems the only way is to use normal documents for storing such large files.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann thanks for the clarification

Comment: So, are you saying to create a xpage/form just to upload the file and then in my Xpage, just point to the file? @Sven seemed to suggest that there might be a better way to embed video onto an Xpage. I'm open to suggestions if my way doesn't make sense...

Comment: Placing such large objects into a NSF design sounds pretty bad to me. I would consider storing those files into the filesystem and rellying on a _URL Mapping_ document to make files available to HTTP task.

Answer (score 0):

NotesIn9 has a nice media library example posted on OpenNTF. Search: 'XPages Media Library'.